# How to debug two node applications at same time using node's built-in debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I debug my node applications by executing node debug app in my application folder.However if i want to use the same with other application at same time it shows me error.

How can i use debug with the other application too?

Comment: What command do you run to debug?

Comment: node's debug port is being used by the first process. for your second app, start it specifying another port using the `--debug` flag like `node --debug=5859 app.js`. Then open another terminal window and connect to the second process's debugging port using `node debug localhost:5859`. ta-da.

Comment: @cviejo: debugger in my code is not working by using this

Comment: @bolav : i am using  node debug app and by using this my pro gramme gets break on the line where i put my debugger

Comment: @AtulAgrawal, yes, sorry, the right flag is `--debug-brk=5859`, not `debug=5859`. Follow the exact instructions above with that change. I'll post is as an answer with the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node's default debug port is being used by the first process. Start your second app specifying another port using the `--debug-brk` or the `--debug` flag like this:

```
node --debug-brk=5859 app.js
```

Then open another terminal window and connect to the second process's debugging port using:

```
node debug localhost:5859
```

Comment: For anyone looking it should be now --inspect-brk=<PORT>